# Java codeSource null pointers when trying to to get local jar paths

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have a java app that needs to know where it is located once it is exported to an executable jar. So, I have the following function in my code:

```
        private void setLocalJarPaths() throws URISyntaxException{
             CodeSource codeSource = ShopRecipient.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
             File jarFile = new File(codeSource.getLocation().toURI().getPath());
             localJarPath =  ShopRecipient.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath(); //getgetgetgetgetgetgetget
             localParentPath = jarFile.getParentFile().getPath();
        }
```

This works when I am running from eclipse, but as soon as I export it to a runnable jar file, it throws the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at bsReportSender.ShopRecipient.setLocalJarPaths(ShopRecipient.java:71)
    at bsReportSender.ShopRecipient.<init>(ShopRecipient.java:23)
    at
```

I've tried changing the class to a different class in the same package, but it still throws that same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Invoking `getPath` does not work if the URI is opaque. That’s possible with file URIs like `file:C:\somePath\someFile`. This URI has no path in the sense of a URI. However, fixing it is quite easy. Just remove the `getPath` invocation:

```
File jarFile = new File(codeSource.getLocation().toURI());
```